# Finding whether two geo-coordinates x and y for 2 different cars lie on the same road

Tags: bigdata, data-analysis, data-science, hpcc

my data consists of vehicle_ID, x and y coordinates (for location), the speed of the vehicle, time at which they travel. And we would like to know which cars are taking the same roads?

this is a sample of my data with 1 vehicle with ID 1 , I have 700000 vehicle ids to analyse

so basically I need insights on how we can figure out what are the different roads and how can we seprate 1 road from another?

```
time   vehicleID            X           Y          speed
37081   1                   13379.67    13854.72    0
37082   1                   13379.322   13852.335   2.41
37083   1                   13378.634   13847.615   4.77
37084   1                   13377.623   13840.689   7
37085   1                   13376.545   13833.297   7.47
37086   1                   13375.136   13826.096   7.34
37087   1                   13373.474   13818.24    8.03
37088   1                   13371.802   13810.335   8.08
37089   1                   13370.169   13802.616   7.89
37090   1                   13368.569   13795.053   7.73
37091   1                   13366.955   13787.422   7.8
37092   1                   13365.392   13780.035   7.56
37093   1                   13363.871   13772.844   7.35
37094   1                   13363.711   13765.055   7.87
37095   1                   13364.266   13758.629   6.45
37096   1                   13364.638   13754.325   4.31
37097   1                   13357.84    13745.829   6.5
37098   1                   13349.609   13743.875   8.46
37099   1                   13339.753   13741.536   10.14
37100   1                   13328.213   13738.797   11.86
37101   1                   13314.81    13735.516   13.8
37102   1                   13303.798   13732.684   11.37
37103   1                   13295.846   13730.64    8.2
37104   1                   13290.481   13729.26    5.54
37105   1                   13272.703   13727.245   7.4
37106   1                   13263.911   13727.606   8.79
37107   1                   13253.599   13728.03    10.32
37108   1                   13241.689   13728.52    11.92
37109   1                   13228.271   13729.071   13.43
37110   1                   13214.942   13729.619   13.34
37111   1                   13201.094   13730.188   13.86
37112   1                   13188.944   13730.687   12.16
37113   1                   13179.592   13731.072   9.37
37114   1                   13173.727   13731.317   5.86
37115   1                   13170.45    13731.454   3.28
37116   1                   13149.29    13724.032   5.38
37117   1                   13142.731   13720.212   7.59
37118   1                   13135.04    13715.734   8.9
37119   1                   13122.401   13705.994   10.24
37120   1                   13113.877   13697.358   12.19
37121   1                   13109.867   13685.023   12.97
37122   1                   13095.963   13675.928   13.76
37123   1                   13083.114   13672.126   13.4
37124   1                   13070.658   13668.44    12.98
37125   1                   13058.278   13664.777   12.92
37126   1                   13045.822   13661.091   12.98
37127   1                   13034.085   13657.619   12.24
37128   1                   13026.376   13655.337   8.04
37129   1                   13021.054   13653.763   5.55
37130   1                   13001.211   13641.21    6.93
37131   1                   12994.959   13634.708   9.02
37132   1                   12987.682   13627.139   10.51
37133   1                   12979.33    13618.452   12.05
37134   1                   12970.403   13609.168   12.87
37135   1                   12961.123   13599.515   13.4
37136   1                   12952.217   13590.252   12.85
37137   1                   12934.75    13572.71    13.69
37138   1                   12924.495   13563.808   13.58
37139   1                   12914.437   13555.076   13.33
37140   1                   12904.507   13546.455   13.15
37141   1                   12894.131   13537.448   13.74
37142   1                   12885.575   13530.02    11.33
37143   1                   12880.01    13525.189   7.37
37144   1                   12876.015   13521.721   5.29
37145   1                   12874.784   13520.652   1.63
37146   1                   12862.971   13510.873   3.16
37147   1                   12859.101   13507.851   4.91
37148   1                   12854.12    13503.961   6.32
37149   1                   12847.949   13499.141   7.83
37150   1                   12840.21    13493.096   9.82
37151   1                   12830.934   13485.852   11.77
37152   1                   12822.446   13479.222   10.76
37153   1                   12814.622   13473.322   9.8
37154   1                   12808.253   13468.581   7.94
37155   1                   12804.065   13465.464   5.22
37156   1                   12802.212   13464.085   2.31
37157   1                   12796.969   13444.202   4.17
37158   1                   12797.734   13438.251   5.99
37159   1                   12798.746   13430.375   7.95
37160   1                   12799.913   13421.29    9.16
37161   1                   12801.268   13410.747   10.63
37162   1                   12802.834   13398.557   12.28
37163   1                   12792.406   13383.284   13.64
37164   1                   12782.269   13374.52    13.39
37165   1                   12772.352   13365.946   13.11
37166   1                   12761.928   13356.934   13.78
37167   1                   12751.965   13348.32    13.17
37168   1                   12744.529   13341.891   9.84
37169   1                   12739.582   13337.614   6.53
37170   1                   12737.259   13335.606   3.07
37171   1                   12732.41    13322.801   5.27
37172   1                   12737.789   13318.106   7.14
37173   1                   12744.69    13312.082   9.16
37174   1                   12753.226   13304.631   11.33
37175   1                   12762.718   13296.345   12.6
37176   1                   12772.421   13287.876   12.88
37177   1                   12782.306   13279.248   13.12
37178   1                   12792.152   13270.653   13.08
37179   1                   12800.333   13263.511   10.86
37180   1                   12805.615   13258.901   7.01
```

Comment: the question is too broad. It would be better if you have posted a shortened fragments for a few vehicles and define the logic of determining the **identical** road

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You will need some database of roads or a service that can tell you name of the road for given coordinates.

If you are solving this for a specific set of countries you should be able to get a database of roads from their public institutions.

Comment: its simulated data though, I thought maybe if you find vehicle paths which is from speed 0 to speed 0 for a specific vehicle id, then we could define routes?? but not sure